# how to add two tables to the html table in c#

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-table

i had a c# code where i was getting a table from sql database and mailing it as html table now i want to send two tables...how can i do that.

what i tried previously:

```
       public static string HtmlTable(DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                string messageBody = "<font> " + "table value" + " </font><br><br>";
                string empty_message = "Null DATA in table value";
                if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    return empty_message;
                }
                string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
                string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
                string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
                string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
                string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
                string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

                messageBody += htmlTableStart;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;

                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    messageBody += htmlTdStart + column + htmlTdEnd;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    messageBody += htmlTrStart;


                    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        messageBody += htmlTdStart;
                        messageBody += item;
                        messageBody += htmlTdEnd;
                    }
                    messageBody += htmlTrEnd;
                }
                messageBody += htmlTableEnd;

                return messageBody;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

the above code only generates one html table but what i need is i will be passing 2 tables. i need two tables to genertaed in my html. i will be passing two tables as arguments.on simple note i need 2 tables to be printed in my html body.

i will be passing two tables or data set which has two tables

public static string HtmlTable(DataTable table,datatable table2)

Comment: What specifically is the problem? What's preventing you from just ending the first HTML table when it has enough rows and then opening another HTML table? You already know which HTML tags open and end HTML tables, so i feel i miss some crucial bit of information about your actual problem...

Comment: I'm not getting u pal.. i need to send two table in this html body..if the second table has no rows it should return an empty message as well like the first one

Comment: I don't understand, i am sorry...

Comment: `HtmlTable(table1); HtmlTable(table2);`

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as including a builder method which will take in a list of DataTable using the seperation of concerns principle and build each table out, returning the end result for you to display to the client.

```cs
public static string HtmlTableBuilder(List<DataTable> tables)
        {
            string tableResponse = "";
            foreach (var table in tables)
            {
                tableResponse += HtmlTable(table);
            }
            return tableResponse;
        }
```

Comment: Pal I'm passing a dataset now which will have two tables..so can u explain that...I'm not getting u.. @Martibo

Comment: So when you say a dataset of two tables, is this not a list of tables? as shown in the example it takes in a list of tables (i.e. 2 tables)

Comment: bro the thing is im returning the html string and mailing it..now i should return two tables in a same mail..that is i shud  pass 2 html string which has a table in each string..so i will be mailing two tables in a single mail

Comment: The above combines a list of tables and returns them as one string, instead of needing to pass a table in as a parameter just create a list, add as many tables as you want and this will combine them.